# Execute multiple async tasks sequentially, continuing on exception

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'd like to execute multiple async tasks sequentially.

```
foreach (var msg in messages)
{
    await smtp.SendAsync(msg);
}
```

**However, if one of the tasks fails, I'd like the rest of them to continue.** And throw one exception at the end.

Think of it like `.WhenAll()` that executes all the tasks and throws an `AggregateException` at the end, if any of the tasks fails. However, I cannot find any *sequential* alternative.

I studied the docs and googled and stackoverflowed for a solution, and I found no built-in way to do this. I think the only way is to handle exceptions manually.

Something like this

```
var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
foreach (var msg in messages)
{
    try
    {
        await smtp.SendAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        exceptions.Add(ex);
    }
}
if (exceptions.Count > 0) 
{
    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
```

Questions:

1. Is there a .NET built-in solution I'm missing?
2. If not, is this the right way? Maybe chaining multiple `.ContinueWith` calls and returning the resulting "chain-task" instead is considered a better practice? (thus eliding await/async and prevent unnecessary state-machine building)
3. Am I allowed to use the .NET built-in `AggregateException` here or this is bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a .NET built-in solution I'm missing?

No. This is an unusual need, so there's nothing built-in. When doing sequential operations, it's far more common to want to *stop* on the first exception.

> If not, is this the right way?

Yes. You can use `AggregateException` if that's the semantics you want. You should prefer `await` over `ContinueWith`.

You may also want to consider a railway programming pattern. There isn't anything like a `Try`/`Error`/`Exceptional` monad in the BCL but there are several libraries out there to fill that gap

Comment: Wow, wasn't expecting an answer from Stephen Cleary. Thanks. Especially for the "prefer await over ContinueWith" part. Upvoted & accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to maintain a list of tasks instead of a list of exceptions. On each iteration you could create one `SendMailAsync` task, put it in the list, and `await` it without throwing the exception. After all tasks have been completed, you could combine them in a single `Task` with the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) method, and finally [`Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) this combined task to propagate all the exceptions in an `AggregateException`:

```
List<Task> tasks = new();
foreach (var msg in messages)
{
    Task task = smtp.SendMailAsync(msg);
    tasks.Add(task);
    await Task.WhenAny(task).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
```

The [`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany) is used as a way to suppress the error of the awaited task. Unfortunately Microsoft hasn't accepted the proposal to [support awaiting a task without throwing](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22144). The `Task.WhenAny` gets the job done, but not in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. Awaiting them one by one and then using `WhenAll` to examine for exceptions.

Comment: @Alex your approach (storing the exceptions) is more straightforward. Storing the tasks would make more sense if you wanted also the results of the successful operations.